# Loop to create series of graphs from different files

Tags: r, loops, plot, histogram

I am trying to plot histograms with long term (several years) mean precipitation (pp) for each day of the month from a series of files. Each file has data collected from a different place (and has a different code). Each of my files looks like this:

```
 X code year month day  pp  
 1 2867 1945     1   1 0.0  
 2 2867 1945     1   2 0.0   
...
```

And I am using the following code:

```
files <- list.files(pattern=".csv")  
par(mfrow=c(4,6))  
for (i in 1:24) {  
    obs <- read.table(files[i],sep=",", header=TRUE)  
    media.dia <- ddply(obs, .(day), summarise, daily.mean<-mean(pp))  
    codigo <- unique(obs$code)  
    hist(daily.mean, main=c("hist per day of month", codigo))  
}
```

I get 24 histograms with 24 different codes in the title, but instead of 24 DIFFERENT histograms from 24 different locations, I get the same histogram 24 times (with 24 different titles). Can anybody tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you define daily.mean?  (Yes, I can see that's the name of a column in media.dia, but you're not passing media.dia to `hist`.)

Comment: I blame the normal distribution. Damned histograms always look the same as n ---> infinity.

Comment: @ brandon- lol my n is not that big, they are definitely the same graph

Comment: Just a bit of stats humour :)

Comment: @ Andrie - daily.mean is the mean pp calculated per day from "media.dia". Is that not enough to define it? If I do   `head(daily.mean)` I get `[1] 0.9579545 1.0464646 1.2237374 0.9840909 1.0205808 0.8277778 `

Comment: It might just be your call to files. Try using [[i]], instead.

Comment: @sbg, Yes, I can see that - but your `hist` function can't see it.  Your call to `ddply` will add a column in media.dia with column name daily.mean.  But media.dia is not attached.  See my answer.

Comment: @brandon, if that were true, then the plot heading would also fail.

Comment: @Brandon - thanks but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Insert `browser()` right after the `{` and go through your code step by step. This is basically what we can do with your non-reproducible example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two errors I can see in your code.

1. There is an error in your `ddply` statement.
2. You are passing the wrong variable to hist, thus plotting something that may or may not exist depending on previous session actions.

The problem in your `ddply` statement is that you are doing an invalid assign (using `<-` ).  Fix this by using `=`:

```
media.dia<- ddply(obs, .(day),summarise, daily.mean = mean(pp))
```

Then edit your `hist` statement:

```
hist(media.dia$daily.mean,main=c("hist per day of month",codigo))
```

I suspect the problem is that you are not passing the correct parameter to `hist`.  The reason that your code actually produces a plot at all, is because in some previous step in your session you must have created a variable called `daily.mean` (as Brandon points out in the comment.)

Comment: Interesting, perhaps he had daily.mean calculated as another object in the workspace and that's why he was not getting an error messgae?

Comment: @brandon.  Yes, exactly.  I'm certain that's what's happening.

Comment: Thanks but it gives an error: `Error in hist.default(media.dia$daily.mean, main = c("hist per day of month",  :'x' must be numeric`

Comment: OK, I've spotted another error in your code.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: you are right, I close r and open it again, and now I get an error. I think the problem is with the `media.dia<- ddply(obs, .(day),summarise, daily.mean<-mean(pp))` because it is giving a column with days and another with NAs

Answer (score 0):

I think the `daily.mean` calculated in the `ddply` function is assigned in a separate environment, and does not exist in an environment `hist` can see.

Try `daily.mean<<-mean(pp)`

Comment: Assigning to upstream environments using `<<-` should only be used on very rare occasions, and this is not one of them.  The `<-` should be a `=`

Comment: @Andrie I agree, your solution is more appropriate. Didn't really think why the OP was assigning in the ddply statement in the first place.

Comment: Simple error, is my guess.  It's happened to me frequently enough, especially when coding `data.frame` statments.